# How to get only specified values record from multiple values of one Record in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

i have a table 'DEMO' like below, I need some specified result in my select query

```
 PID   Is_Viewed
  1      False          
  1      False     
  1      False      
  1      False  
  2      True
  2      False
```

Now i need to select only those record which if having even a single value 'True' then result will be 1 else 0 in select statment. i have tried much but not getting the desired result... my query is

```
/// select statement
    SELECT distinct PId,CASE WHEN EXISTS(Select Is_Viewed from DEMO where Is_viewed=1) then 1 else 0 end as Is_viewed FROM DEMO


    i WANT result like

    PId     Is_Viewed
    1        0
    2        1
```

Comment: By the way, there's a bit type in sql server, to manage boolean values...

Comment: What is the `Is_Viewed` type (bit or INT)?

Comment: ya.. it's also bit type in table means in form of True/false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    PId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Is_Viewed='True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Is_Viewed
FROM
    DEMO
GROUP BY
    PId
```

**Edit**

Considering the data that you have supplied.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(PID INT,Is_Viewed VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
(1,'False'),          
(1,'False'),  
(1,'False'),      
(1,'False'),  
(2,'True'),
(2,'False')
```

With this query

```
SELECT
    PId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Is_Viewed='True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Is_Viewed
FROM
    @tbl AS tbl
GROUP BY
    PId
```

The output is this:

```
PId     Is_Viewed
1       0
2       1
```

Comment: thanks for your response.... but it's not working.For PId 1 it's giving the result  1 but it should give it to 0

Comment: sorry dude... actually i have made changes to table and considering the old one. thanks ...it's working.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `Is_Viewed` is defined as a `bit` type since SQL server doesn't have a BOOLEAN type. Then try this:

```
SELECT PID,
       MAX(CAST(Is_Viewed as INT)) as Is_Viewed 
FROM T
GROUP BY PID
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1c61/4)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(PID INT,Is_Viewed VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
(1,'False'),          
(1,'False'),  
(1,'False'),      
(1,'False'),  
(2,'True'),
(2,'False')



select distinct t.PID,
    CASE WHEN t.Is_Viewed = 'TRUE' 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As PType from @tbl t
    INNER JOIN 
        (Select MIN(PID)As PID,Is_Viewed 
                FROM @tbl
GROUP BY  Is_Viewed)AS KK
ON KK.PID = t.PID
AND KK.Is_Viewed = t.Is_Viewed
```